# How to capture OutlookContact.Write event?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-2007

I am trying to hook a method with Application.ItemLoad event:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.ItemLoad += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler(Application_ItemLoad);
}
```

Which would check if current item is ContactItem. If it is a ContactItem it would check if the property ContactItem.User4 contains value `xxx`. If ContactItem.User4 contains value `xxx`, it would hook another method with ContactItem.Write event:

```
void Application_ItemLoad(object Item)
        {
            if (Item is Outlook.ContactItem)
            {
                Outlook.ContactItem contact = (Outlook.ContactItem)Item;
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("A new contact is loaded into memory");

                try
                {
                    string user4 = contact.User4;
                    bool isSynchronized =  user4 != null && user4.Contains("xxx");

                    if (isSynchronized)
                    {
                        contact.Write += propertyChangeHandler;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: "+e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the problem is, whenever I try to access ContactItem.User4 property, I get an exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The item's properties and
>   methods cannot be used inside this event procedure.

What should I do that I don't get the above error?

Thanks for reading my long question and looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different event. According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/41daf68c-3dc2-49f4-b717-10a54ee6fcb6/) - the contents of the item are not yet loaded into memory. You should look at the `Application.Inspectors` event [`NewInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147644%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for response. The problem in executing the steps of Application_ItemLoad with NewInspector event is that propertyChangeHandler is hooked multiple times with ContactItem.Write event. Can we ensure that it is hooked only once?

Comment: You should disconnect the handler after the inspector is closed. Use `((Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector).Close += new Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_CloseEventHandler(Inpsector_Close);`

Comment: And where should I put this code? If I insert it into NewInspector event handler, CloseEventHandler will again get attached multiple times with one inspector. Besides, Inspector_Close callback method doesn't have any parameter. Even if I hook this method with Close event, how will I get reference to current inspector or item from whose Write event I need to disconnect a handler?

Comment: @craftsman You need to implement an Inspector Wrapper http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff973716.aspx

Comment: @SilverNinja Thanks a lot for suggestion. InspectorWrapper works great.